# How to connect Microsoft Graph using python without UI Interaction?

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following this link> [python-sample-send-mail](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-send-mail) to send email, but I would like to skip or authenticate the user on background without any UI interaction. I don't like the idea that OAuth: pop up a window.

My application is registered in Microsoft Azure AD.

I would like to know how to authenticate with a Email username and a password without UI interaction.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The purpose of OAuth is to securely authenticate a user via username/password. Hardcoding these into an application is a _substantial_ security hole and really shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the doc:[AAD V2.0 end pointRestrictions on protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-protocols) ,[The OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) is not supported by the v2.0 endpoint.

In [python ADAL sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-keyvault-java/issues/5) , client secret is not accepted by acquire_token_with_username_password method, so you need to register `native` app.

***Sample code:***

```
import adal
import requests

tenant = ""
client_id = "app id"
# client_secret = ""

username = ""
password = "”

authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant
RESOURCE = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)

# Use this for Client Credentials
#token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
#    RESOURCE,
#    client_id,
#    client_secret
#    )

# Use this for Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC)
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(RESOURCE, username, password, client_id)

graph_api_endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0{0}'

# /me only works with ROPC, for Client Credentials you'll need /<UsersObjectId/
request_url = graph_api_endpoint.format('/me')
headers = {
'User-Agent' : 'python_test',
'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(token["accessToken"]),
'Accept' : 'application/json',
'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url = request_url, headers = headers)
print (response.content)
```

In addition, native app is not necessary if you use REST API, but `client secret` need to be set.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay!  I will try, also now I am able to send a email via postman and my app now is classified as Web app / API in portal azure. I followed the flow 2 of this precious article [http://codematters.tech/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oauth-rest-api/] (http://codematters.tech/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oauth-rest-api/)  that made me able to send a email, write the request that I did in postman will be pretty straightforward in python.

Comment: @Luis L Hi,if you think my answer is useful,you could mark it for answer. Thanks a lot.